# Python guessing game, replace blanks with letter and store in a list

Tags: python

Basically I am trying to make a hangman type game. When a letter is guessed that is in the word I want that letter to stay there during the next round. I tried doing this with a list but I couldn't figure out how to get it to replace the specific blank with the letter.

And yes I have read the other questions on this topic but could not get them to work for me.

```
import random
import time

def intro():
    print ('''Welcome to the word guessing game!
    You will have 6 letter guesses to figure out my word!
    First you must choose a topic.
    Choose from the following: (1) Cars , (2) Diseases ,
    (3) Animals , or (4) Mathematical Words''')

def optionSelect():
    choice = ''
    while choice != '1' and choice != '2' and choice !='3' and choice !='4':
        choice = input()
    return choice

def checkChoice(chosenOption):
    if chosenOption == '1':
        sectionOne()
    elif chosenOption == '2':
        sectionTwo()
    elif chosenOption == '3':
        sectionThree()
    elif chosenOption == '4':
        sectionFour()
    else:
        print('You didnt choose an option...')

def sectionOne():
    words = ['mclaren ', 'bugatti ', 'aston martin ', 'mitsubishi ']
    randWord = random.choice(words)
    blanks = '_ ' * len(randWord)
    guessing(blanks, randWord)


def sectionTwo():
    words = ['gonorrhea ', 'nasopharyngeal carcinoma ', 'ependymoma ', 'tuberculosis ']
    randWord = random.choice(words)
    blanks = '_ ' * len(randWord)
    guessing(blanks, randWord)



def sectionThree():
    words = ['tardigrade ', 'komodo dragon ', 'bontebok ', 'ferruginous hawk ']
    randWord = random.choice(words)
    blanks = '_ ' * len(randWord)
    guessing(blanks, randWord)


def sectionFour():
    words = ['pythagorean ', 'differentiation ', 'polyhedron ', 'googolplex ']
    randWord = random.choice(words)
    blanks = '_ ' * len(randWord)
    guessing(blanks, randWord)


def guessing(blanks, randWord):
    missed = []
    print ()
    print ("Word: ",blanks)
    attempts = 15
    while attempts != 0:
        attempts = attempts - 1
        print ('Guess a letter, you have ' + str(attempts) + ' attempts left.')
        guessLetter = input()
        if guessLetter in randWord:
            newBlanks = " ".join(c if c in guessLetter else "_" for c in randWord)
            print ('Correct!')
            print ()
            print ("Word: ",newBlanks)
        else:
                  missed.append(guessLetter)
                  print ('That letter is not in the word, you have guessed the following letters:')
                  print (', '.join(missed))
                  print ()


playAgain = ''
while playAgain != 'yes' and playAgain!= 'no':
    intro()
    optionNumber = optionSelect()
    checkChoice(optionNumber)
    print('Do you want to play again? (yes or no)')
    #Play again or not
    playAgain = input()
    if playAgain == 'yes':
        played = 1
        playAgain =''
    else:
        print('Thanks for Playing! Bye!')
        time.sleep(2)
        quit()
```

Comment: What exactly is not working in your code? Or at least where do you think it has an issue?

Comment: What precisely do you want to store? The random word, or the users attempts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you do not store your newBlanks, so every time the user guesses a right letter, the program recreates the string. So you need to keep track of what letters are guessed correctly. You can do so by replacing every guessed letter in a local variable that's not revalued in the if statement. You can fix that by using the following while loop:

```
while attempts != 0:
    attempts = attempts - 1
    print ('Guess a letter, you have ' + str(attempts) + ' attempts left.')
    guessLetter = input()
    if guessLetter in randWord:
        newBlanks = " ".join(c if c in guessLetter else "_" for c in randWord)
        index = 0
        for letter in newBlanks:
            if letter != '_' and letter != ' ':
                blanks= blanks[:index] + letter + blanks[index+1:]
            index += 1
        print ('Correct!')
        print ()
        print ("Word: ",blanks)
```

ps, some of your words have blank spaces in them, you might wanna make sure space is not considered as a guess

Answer (score 1):

The line where you set the newBlanks variable only worries about the currently entered letter. There is no storage for the letters that have previously been guessed in the guessing function.

You can make a list for the successfully guessed letters and check if each character in randWord matches one of the letters in that list instead of just the last successfully guessed character.

The list is called 'got' in my example.

```
def guessing(blanks, randWord):
    missed = []
    got = [] #successful letters
    print ()
    print ("Word: ",blanks)
    attempts = 15
    while attempts != 0:
        attempts = attempts - 1
        print ('Guess a letter, you have ' + str(attempts) + ' attempts left.')
        guessLetter = input()
        if guessLetter in randWord:
            #add the letter to the 'got' list
            got.append(guessLetter)
            #newBlanks now adds in all successful letters
            newBlanks = " ".join(c if c in got else '_' for c in randWord)
            print ('Correct!')
            print ()
            print ("Word: ",newBlanks)
        else:
            missed.append(guessLetter)
            print ('That letter is not in the word, you have guessed the following letters:')
            print (', '.join(missed))
            print ()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a class to store the previously guessed answer, and have all the functions as methods:

```
class Hangman:
    def __main__(self):
       self.last_word = ''

    def intro(self):
       print ('''Welcome to the word guessing game!
       You will have 6 letter guesses to figure out my word!
       First you must choose a topic.
       Choose from the following: (1) Cars , (2) Diseases ,
       (3) Animals , or (4) Mathematical Words''')

    def optionSelect(self):
       self.choice = ''
       while choice != '1' and choice != '2' and choice !='3' and choice !='4':
       self.choice = input()
       return self.choice

    def checkChoice(self, chosenOption):
        if chosenOption == '1':
           self.sectionOne()
        elif chosenOption == '2':
            self.sectionTwo()
        elif chosenOption == '3':
           self.sectionThree()
        elif chosenOption == '4':
           self.sectionFour()
        else:
            print('You didnt choose an option...')

      def sectionOne(self):
         self.words = ['mclaren ', 'bugatti ', 'aston martin ', 'mitsubishi ']
         randWord = random.choice(words)
         self.blanks = '_ ' * len(randWord)
         self.guessing(blanks, randWord)
     #the rest of the sections have been omitted for brevity

      def guessing(self, blanks, randWord):
           self.missed = []
          print ()
          print ("Word: ",blanks)
          self.attempts = 15
          while self.attempts != 0:
          self.attempts -= 1
          print ('Guess a letter, you have ' + str(self.attempts) + '   attempts left.')
          self.guessLetter = input()
          if guessLetter in randWord:
              newBlanks = " ".join(c if c in guessLetter else "_" for c in randWord)
              print ('Correct!')
              print ()
              print ("Word: ",self.newBlanks)
              self.last_word = self.newBlanks #here, we are storing the word that is correct
           else:
              missed.append(self.guessLetter)
              print ('That letter is not in the word, you have guessed the following letters:')
              print (', '.join(self.missed))
              self.last_word = self.missed
              print ()

playAgain = ''
the_game = Hangman()
while playAgain != 'yes' and playAgain!= 'no':

     the_game.intro()
     optionNumber = the_game.optionSelect()
     the_game.checkChoice(optionNumber)
     print('Do you want to play again? (yes or no)')
     #Play again or not
     playAgain = input()
     if playAgain == 'yes':
        played = 1
        playAgain =''
     else:
         print('Thanks for Playing! Bye!')
         time.sleep(2)
         quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
randWord = "something"
blanks = len("something")*"_ "
guessLetter = "t"

print(blanks)
if guessLetter in randWord:
    for index, letter in enumerate(randWord, 0):
        if guessLetter == randWord[index]:
            temp = list(blanks)
            temp[2*index] = guessLetter
            blanks = "".join(temp)
print(blanks)
```

There are more pytonish way to do it, but judging on your code, I prefer not to show it to you.